# chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(namedFunction) - function scope

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, scope

I am developing a browser extension using Chrome API. For this specific task, I need to add a listener for the ***chrome.tabs.onUpdated*** event, using a named function, since I need to remove it on completion.

The issue appears when I set this listener inside other event listeners - more concretely, for the ***DOMContentLoaded*** and ***click*** events.

```
/* This Works */

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(namedFunction);
function namedFunction(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        console.log('Tab loaded: ' + tab.url);
    }

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(namedFunction);
    return;
}

/* This doesnt work */

function namedFunction(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        console.log('Tab loaded: ' + tab.url);
    }

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(namedFunction);
    return;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var start_btn = document.getElementById('btn-start');

    if (start_btn) {
        start_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(namedFunction);
            chrome.tabs.create( {'url': currentUrl} );
        });
    }

});
```

The code above is contained in a background script. Snippet of the ***manifest.json***:

```
  "background":{
    "scripts": ["script.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "background"
  ],
```

I imagine this has to do with the *"function variable scope"*. On the code example that doesn't work, a tab is still created when I click the button, so I have access to *'chrome.'*, but *namedFunction* isn't called by the event listener I set.

Comment: If this is the popup script, opening a new tab without `active: false` option will close your popup so no code will run anymore. You'll need a background script for this.

Comment: I forgot to add that the code presented is in a background script. Manifest contains   "background":{ "scripts": ["script.js"] }.

Comment: DOMContentLoaded in the background script doesn't do anything useful because the background page is a separate page which is loaded when the browser profile is initialized. It has no visible parts so your click events don't do anything useful. See the [extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) - you probably need a popup script or a content script depending on the user interaction.

Comment: Like I denote in the question, the DOMContentLoaded and click event listeners do work - in the popup, I have a 'Start' button, when I press it, a new tab IS opened by chrome.tabs.create({...}). The issue is with the chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener, that I can't associate with any named functions, unless I set this listener in the main code scope, outside of any other listeners.

Comment: Apparently you load the same script in both the background page and the popup page. These two are completely different and shouldn't use the same script. Anyway, I'm just guessing since you didn't show how you load that script.

Comment: Thanks for your input and yes, I believed this was being caused by a function scope issue, but reading the 'Content Scripts' documentation, this may be a problem with my implementation. What is strange is that I don't think this is a runtime issue, since the Listener works perfectly when added outside other structures.